# List functions in fish config file?

Tags: fish

How can I list all the functions I have saved in the config file?

I tried `functions | cat`, but that listed a bunch of functions that are not in my config folder.

Comment: You have to parse config files, fish usually  finds them in ./config/fish/functions and in /usr/share/fish/config.fish . Perhaps there is way to run with with only one config file and execute `functions -n` from ot

Answer (score 2):

Iterate over the known function names then use `functions -details $f` to get the file it was defined in and filter on that info.

```
for f in (functions)
    if string match '*/.config/fish/config.fish' (functions --details $f)
        echo $f
    end
end
```